# How to @import without including all CSS but just the @extends ones

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, gulp, stylus

I'm using stylus with bootstrap-stylus. This is my `app.styl` code

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap-stylus/lib/bootstrap.styl";
section
    @extend .row
```

After i run gulp, I notice that complete bootstrap css is included to the target `app.css`. I want to dynamically include just the `.row rule` using  `@extend`. what I'm trying to get is this..

```
section { //.row rules
    zoom: 1;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

Is it possible? What am I missing? Is it possible with SASS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK both stylus and sass do not support importing only certain selectors of a file. If you have control over the imported file, though, you could use SASS [placeholder selectors](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholder_selectors_) instead of classes/ids. A placeholder selector is some sort of abstract selector which simply doesn't render anything by default.

```
/* _partial.scss */
%some-selector {
  prop: value;
}
%another-selector {
  prop: value;
}

/* main.scss */
@import 'partial';
.some-class {
  @extend %some-selector;
}
```

results in the not-extended placeholder selectors being ignored (in this case `%another-selector`)

```
/* output.css */
.some-class {
  prop: value;
}
```

Comment: Just found out.. Stylus do have placeholder selectors
`$some-selector {
  prop: value;
}

/* main.scss */
@import 'partial';
.some-class {
  @extend $some-selector;
}`